# How i could combinate this two SQL statement?

Tags: sql

How i could combinate this two SQL statement. and make them run together at call.

```
 SELECT  tovar,kod,
          100/SUM(CASE WHEN co='prijem' THEN kusy ELSE NULL END)*
          SUM(CASE WHEN co='predaj' THEN kusy ELSE NULL END) as percenta,
          SUM(CASE WHEN co='prijem' THEN kusy ELSE NULL END) AS prijate_ks,
          SUM(CASE WHEN co='predaj' THEN kusy ELSE NULL END) AS predane_ks
from jednotypredaj WHERE (datum BETWEEN '$a' AND '$b') and (tovar LIKE '%$search%')  
group by tovar 
ORDER by predane_ks DES
```

and this statement

```
"INSERT INTO datadocasne 
      (fromd,tod) 
 VALUES 
      ('$a','$b')";
```

Thanks for help

Comment: Welcome to SO.  Please include table structure of both tables, example expected results and sample data when asking this style of question.  I'm unsure if you want to insert 5 fields into datadocasne or just 2 and if just 2 which two from the select match to the 2 in the insert?

Comment: Hi Thanks for answer. i do not need to combinate this two statement i just need them run at once. if possible in one sql syntax. ok i am going to get table structure. thanks

Comment: Why? Just issue two calls.. if they have to be run at once write a package/procedure that accepts parameters to run both.

Comment: a ok i understand i will try to do it this way.

Comment: Well if it is only a one time query to run, why not just press f5 for sql server or Run as script for PL SQL. For fun you could always add the lines for a stroed proc and run the stored proc.

Answer (score 0):

Put your statements between

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION
```

and

```
COMMIT;
```